# yum: same settings on 2 servers, different results

Tags: centos, yum

I have CentOS running on 2 servers, both with yum 3.2.19. duplicity is showing up on one server but not the other. I checked the repolist and they match:

Server1:

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: pubmirrors.reflected.net
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * addons: chi-10g-1-mirror.fastsoft.net
 * extras: mirrors.greenmountainaccess.net
repo id              repo name                                status
addons               CentOS-5 - Addons                        enabled:       0
base                 CentOS-5 - Base                          enabled:   2,508
c5-media             CentOS-5 - Media                         disabled
centosplus           CentOS-5 - Plus                          disabled
contrib              CentOS-5 - Contrib                       disabled
extras               CentOS-5 - Extras                        enabled:     311
updates              CentOS-5 - Updates                       enabled:     339
repolist: 3,158
```

Server2:

```
[root@server yum.repos.d]# yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * updates: mirror.trouble-free.net
 * addons: mirror.skiplink.com
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
repo id              repo name                                status
addons               CentOS-5 - Addons                        enabled:       0
base                 CentOS-5 - Base                          enabled:   2,508
c5-media             CentOS-5 - Media                         disabled
centosplus           CentOS-5 - Plus                          disabled
contrib              CentOS-5 - Contrib                       disabled
extras               CentOS-5 - Extras                        enabled:     311
updates              CentOS-5 - Updates                       enabled:     339
repolist: 3,158
```

Server1 sees duplicity in yum:

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum search duplicity
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: pubmirrors.reflected.net
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * addons: chi-10g-1-mirror.fastsoft.net
 * extras: mirrors.greenmountainaccess.net
============================================================ Matched: duplicity =============================================================
duplicity.i386 : Encrypted bandwidth-efficient backup using rsync algorithm
```

Server2 does not see duplicity:

```
[root@server yum.repos.d]# yum search duplicity
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * updates: mirror.trouble-free.net
 * addons: mirror.skiplink.com
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Warning: No matches found for: duplicity
No Matches found
```

What am I missing (trying to get duplicity using yum on Server2)? I know the mirrors are different, but I didn't think that would matter if the repos are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Well first, mirrors don't necessarily always completely 'mirror' the repository.

Second, try to do this first:

```
user@host:[~]$ yum clean all
```

Comment: Note that "yum clean expire-cache" is a much more efficient way to see if there is new data.

Answer (score 1):

The second server shows

Excluding Packages in global exclude list

Check the global exclude list if duplicity is mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- Where did you get 3.2.19 from, that's not a normal yum version for CentOS-5.
- You can disable excludes with --disableexcludes=all, in case one of the machines has excluded certain packages.
- Dito. for disabling plugins (like versionlock) which can exclude packages (--noplugins, or --disableplugin=).
- I'm pretty sure that 3.2.19 repolist will give you the timestamps for the data in the repos. with: yum repolist -v ... then if the timestamps don't match, you want to do "yum clean expire-cache" on the older one (but with a missing package this is least likely).

Answer (score 0):

From looking at what you have here, it seems that you might want to try 'yum --disableplugins' I bet yum on server2 is thinking that one mirror is faster than another on server1. disabling the fastest mirror plugin might help solve your issue. You can also have a look at yum priorities which is a plugin that allows you to set priorities for certain repos.

Here is the yum priorities link:
http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities